# Combine library packages into single node package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I use few libraries again and again in several projects and I want to enforce specific versions into the projects.

Project 1

```
{
  "name": "project_1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

Project 2

```
{
  "name": "project_2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

For any project I would want to put all the packages above `react`, `react-dom`, `react-router` and `react-route-dom` into a single node package (`all-libs`) like below. By this way I can freeze the versions in all projects.

Any Project

```
{
  "name": "project_1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "all-libs": "0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Reason for taking this approach:

1. Centralized version upgrades to avoid version compatibility issues.

My question here is how to Create this package (`all-libs`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can host an own npm package, that has these packages as dependencies. You can set up an own nexus server that can host your package or you can put it on npmjs.

Add this lines to your package.json:

```
"name": "all-libs",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "My Libs for every project",
"author": "Me",
"license": "MIT",
"engines": {
    "node": ">=8.9.3"
},
"publishConfig": {
    "registry": "http://myRegistry.com"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
}
```

And then you can publish it via NPM like this: `npm publish`.

For more information see the documentation about publishing packages: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish

Comment: You answer is interesting. Never knew we could do something like this. I published a package like you suggested (https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js-libs). How do i actually import React and use it in the project? I tried like `import React from 'core-js-libs', `import { React} from 'core-js-libs`` and all such combinations`

Comment: After `npm i core-js-libs`, you import it the same way than before. The react package is installed as dependency from your package and can be used as it were a normal dependency in your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have these packages in one package you would need to somehow expose these libraries in this package:

```
import { React, BrowserHistory, ReactDOM } from 'all-libs';
```

But I would think If this makes sense really. Notice that all mature libraries like `create-react-app` and `nextjs` they all require you to install specific versions by yourself.

Comment: This is the approach I tried before. Thanks anyways. The accepted one is much more easier